# Azure Virtual Network subnet connection issues

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I'm having is that I have one Vnet with 2x /27 subnets that have been delegated to WebApps.

webApp-1 -> subnet1
WebApp-2 -> subnet2.

I've terraformed the Vnet:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main-rg"{
    name = "main-rg"
    location = "westeurope"
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main-vnet" {
  name                = "main-vnet"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main-rg.name
  address_space       = ["172.25.44.0/22"]

  subnet {
    name           = "test"
    address_prefix = "172.25.44.64/27"
    security_group = ""
  }
}


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  name                 = "subnet1"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main-rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.25.44.0/27"]
  
  delegation {
    name = "webapp1delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
      }
    }
  }


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet2" {
  name                 = "subnet2"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main-rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["172.25.44.32/27"]
  
  delegation {
    name = "webapp2delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to connect the WebApps to their respective subnets.
FYI: I'm connecting the WebApps from the Azure Portal (old test resources, don't want to import them as they will be removed soon).
The first on (WebApp1 to Subnet1) works out fine.
When I then try to connect WebApp2 to Subnet2 it fails, but I am able to connect WebApp2 to Subnet1.

I also tried the other way around; I'm able to connect both apps to Subnet2 (but I first have to disconnect both apps from Subnet1).

I'm not seeing any error messages other than a little "Connection failed" popup in the Portal UI.

So I guess my question is: is it not possible to have 2x subnets with WebApp-delegations in one Vnet, or am I missing something?
And again, sorry if this is something blatantly obvious that I've overlooked.

In advance; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have two web apps in the same app service plan to use differently integrated subnets because all web apps in the same app service plan could share the VNet integration. However, you can use each integrated subnet for each app service plan. You could read the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration):

> The integration subnet can be used by only one App Service plan.

> You can have only one regional VNet Integration per App Service plan.
> Multiple apps in the same App Service plan can use the same VNet.

To avoid any issues with subnet capacity, a `/26` subnet address mask with 64 addresses is the recommended size.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I was not aware that one of my developers was leeching of the other developers app service plan (and did not think to check). Thank you for enlightening me!:)